# Firebase Firestore server side rules - problems

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an app in iOS that I'm nearly complete and I'm working to configure the server side rules in Firestore.  I'm copying the rules identically to another app I have which users the same authentication and database structure.  This set of code is not working however.

My data structure has two root collections: User and Feed.  Feed is a public collection that any authenticated user should be able to access.

The User Collection and sub collections should only be accessible to the authenticated user who is logged in.

The feed access is working correctly here, but I'm not able to read and presumably not write anything to the user collection/subcollections.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    match /feed/{docId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  
  }
}
```

This works - so it is established that the authentication is working. The user documentID is the same as the UID in the authentication table.  I'm going nuts with this.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
     
       allow read: if request.auth != null;

    }

  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with this - I still don't understand why my other app works but not this one.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    match /feed/{docId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding why the same code is working in your other app, it seems to be related with the data structure in both applications and the use of the [single-segment or recursive wildcards][1]. 

  [1]: https://firebase.google.cn/docs/rules/rules-language?hl=en&%3Bauthuser=19&authuser=19#:~:text=Single-segment,path%20object